# Break out of Python for loop

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop, break

I was wondering if there's a way I can have my for loop print out the statement right after the 5th  loop instead of calling it 6 times and stopping at 5 using my if statement.

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this? Thanks.

```
for counter in range (6):
  if counter == 5:
    print("Maximum speed reached!\n")
    break ##Break out of loop if condition met.
  myCar.accelerate()
  time.sleep(1) ##Add 1 second delay each loop.
```

Comment: use starting point in range (i,j) this way loop will iterate i to j-1 in your case range(1,6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just iterate until 5 instead of 6 and print your message out of the loop:

```
for counter in range(5):
    # Remove the if statement:
    # if counter == 5:
    #     print("")
    #     break
    myCar.accelerate()
    time.sleep(1)

print("Maximum speed reached!")
```

Comment: You're right. Now that I thought about it I should remove the unnecessary if statement and just add the print statement outside of loop after loop statement. I was over-complicating this lol. Ty.